# VsVim automatically switching to select mode

Tags: vim, visual-studio-2013, vsvim

I am using the current version of VsVim in Visual Studio 2013 and there is one behavior that I cannot work with and that is when I am in insert mode, and I select text, it automatically switches to select mode. I want to explicitly state when I want to be in select mode so that when I'm in insert mode, I stay there.

Answer (score 0):

Play with different `mouse` options. Maybe this will suit you the most:

```
set mouse=n
```